# Why doesn't Spark's LongAccumulator implement equals()

Tags: java, apache-spark

I just realized that Spark's `LongAccumulator` (`org.apache.spark.util.LongAccumulator`: [API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html)) does not implements its own `equals()`, but instead inherits `Object#equals()` which only compares identities of objects rather than the values in the object.  Do you know why is the reason behind this?

Comment: Presumably the authors did not expect you to want to compare accumulators with value semantics. It does seem a bit odd that you would want that.

Comment: @khelwood -- Can you elaborate on why doing a value `equals()` is odd?  I am doing this in unit test and an accumulator is embedded in a object which I do want to do a value `equals()`

Comment: This seems natural to me: two accumulators which happen to have the same value at the moment are not the same. You could object that this isn't the rule for collections, but: 1. this is partly inherited from Java; 2. mutability is kind of the point for accumulators. 

"an accumulator is embedded in a object which I do want to do a value equals()"

Nothing stops you from calling `.value` in your own `equals()`.